# Show all users related to tenant in one place

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant, saas

I'm working on an application in the saas model (django 2.1). I use the django tenants plugin (https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants).

My problem is to display all tenants in the "public" schema. In such a way as to see how much each tenant has users, to be able to manage them, etc.
Is it a good architectural solution to put a foreign key into Tenant in the User model and save this column during the registration process?

Is there another way to do it?

Below is example, pseudo code:

```
class Tenant(TenantMixin):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name of company'), max_length=50, unique=True)
    on_trial = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    paid_until = models.DateTimeField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    auto_create_schema = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


class Domain(DomainMixin):
    pass


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('Email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('First name'), max_length=60, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last name'), max_length=60, blank=True)
    member_of_company = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question but, do you need to share users between tenants? (i.e. does the same user need to be able to access two or more different tenants?) Becuase if not then you can simply store the `User` model in a `TENANT_APPLICATION` instead. Then each tenant will have its own users.

Comment: I need all tenants with users (without sharing between tenants) in admin panel

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your tenants and get the Users for each tenant with the following code:

```py
from django.db import connection
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from tenant_schemas.utils import get_tenant_model


UserModel = get_user_model()
TenantModel = get_tenant_model()
for tenant in TenantModel.objects.all():
    connection.set_tenant(tenant)
    tenant_users = UserModel.objects.all()
    # Do whatever you want with your users
```